# CouchDB 2.0 multiple replications

Tags: database, apache, couchdb, admin, replication

**Is there a way to replicate all Databases from CouchDB in one time?**

Example :
I have multiple DBs

- users
- articles
- groups

Each DB contains multiples unique documents, and instead of replicate each DB independently I would like to replicate all of them.

Furthermore, I saw that CouchDB 2.0 allow DB replication, even if you do not have admin access, is that normal ?

Best regards
Sim

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to put all document types into the same database, so you can replicate all documents at once. It's common practice to use a property `type` to differentiate between different types:

```
{
  "_id": "org.couchdb.user:bob",
  "type": "user",
  "name": "bob"
},
{
  "_id": "article.2017-12-16T15:30:00.000Z",
  "type": "article",
  "title": "About Replication",
  "text": "Replication rocks!"
}
```

You can then use a Mango query to get all documents of a certain type.

Comment: Yes I used the "type" to differentiate, but once you start to have a lot of document types, (that involve a lot of views), each document added in the database involve to index each design view, This reindexing process can be problematic if you want to scale.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to split the databases into "replication groups" then if you are concerned about reindexing speed. If you provide more details about what your particular use case is, I can try to help with a more specific answer. Right now I could only see 3 types that don't sound very volatile (users, groups and articles).

Comment: Yes the example above is not my real use case.
I have multiples databases. Each database contain only one type of data (user, articles, ...). My question is, what's the best process to replicate each DB. Or maybe I should go back to the "type" pattern.

Comment: You should definitively use the "type" property for each document. Then replicate each type into a common database, and replicate from those into a common database. Replicating different databases separately if you need the docs together doesn't sound right to me at all. Instead, use the strenghts of CouchDB to your advantage ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The approach can be one db per user
and creating skilled dbs manager by internal replication,
filter by type from all db-users